Derivation of the Dirac exchange-energy formula
So I have been reading the textbook "Density Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules" by Parr and Yang, and in chapter 6, their derivation of the Dirac exchange-energy functional $K_D[\rho]$ started with:
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
K_D[\rho] = \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{s}|\rho(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2)|^2 d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2
\end{equation}
with $s = |\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|$ and $\rho(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2)$ being the first order reduced density matrix, which they calculate to be:
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\rho(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2) = 3 \rho(\mathbf{r}) \left[ \frac{\sin t - t \cos t}{t^3} \right],
\end{equation}
with $t = k_F(\mathbf{r}) s$, $k_F = (3 \pi^2 \rho(\mathbf{r}))^{1/3}$ is the Fermi momentum in a.u. and $\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{r}_1 + \mathbf{r}_2)$ and $\mathbf{s} = |\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|\mathbf{e}_z$ (you can find more details in the free preview of the book here, sec. 6.1, p.107-108).
Now, the issue that I have is in the second line of their equation (6.1.20), where seemingly they just replaced equation $(2)$ in $(1)$ to get:
\begin{equation}  \tag{3}
K_D[\rho] = 9\pi \int \rho^2(\mathbf{r}) \frac{1}{k_F^2} d\mathbf{r} \int_0^\infty  \frac{\left(\sin t - t \cos t \right)^2}{t^5} dt.
\end{equation}
Maybe I a missing something very basic here, but I honestly can't see how they got there, here is what I get instead:
\begin{align}  \tag{4}
K_D[\rho] &= \frac{9}{4} \iint \rho^2(\mathbf{r}) \frac{\left(\sin t - t \cos t \right)^2}{s t^6} ds d\mathbf{r}, \\\\
 &= \frac{9}{4} \iint \rho^2(\mathbf{r}) \frac{1}{k_F^2} \frac{1}{s^2} \frac{\left(\sin t - t \cos t \right)^2}{t^5} k_F ds d\mathbf{r}, \\\\
 &= \frac{9}{4} \iint \rho^2(\mathbf{r}) \frac{\left(\sin t - t \cos t \right)^2}{t^7} d\mathbf{r} dt.
\end{align}
As you can see it seems that I am missing a factor $4\pi s^2$ inside the integral and I am not sure where it should come from, is it somehow related to a change of variables to spherical coordinates so that one gets something like $\int d\mathbf{s} \rightarrow \int s^2 ~ ds \int_0^\pi \sin \theta ~d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi$? If so, how can it be justified?
If anyone has any idea or can nudge me in the right direction, I would be truly grateful.
Thanks!

Not trying to answer my own question here, but it seems to me that what they did, is calculating the integral $\iint d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2$ over the whole space by fixing one particle say at a position $\mathbf{r}$ and changing the position of the other particle using spherical coordinates with the radius $s = |\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|$, equal to the distance between the two particles, going from $0$ to $\infty$. Then it would make sense that we are left with the transformation at the end of my question. I would leave this here if maybe someone has better insights or comments...

Is there a typo in $\mathbf{s} = (\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2) \cdot \mathbf{e}_z$? The LHS is typeset as a vector but the RHS looks like it should be scalar. Either way, I suspect you make a mistake when converting the volume element during the variable substitution.

Yes thank you, I corrected the typo. It could be that I am doing a mistake but at the same time, they started with an integral with two vector variables (equation (1)) and in the second line they have an integral with only one vector variable and a scalar (equation (4)), which makes me think that they skipped some steps without mentioning them. The most plausible answer I could come up with is this substitution where they fix one variable and only change the other using spherical coordinates in order to integrate over the whole space.
